# Automapper won't install on my UWP project anymore

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, nuget, automapper

I've been working on an UWP app for some time now, and a couple of weeks ago I installed Automapper and got it up and running. Worked perfectly, no issues, until today when I was going to continue working on my project. I went through a system restore before it stopped working, and I also updated to the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

The problem: Visual Studio suddenly couldn't recognize the reference. Despite having already installed it, I tried to uninstall and then install it again, but without success. Now it complaints about compatibility. Example:

> Checking compatibility for System.Globalization.Extensions 4.3.0 with UAP,Version=v10.0.16299 (win10-x86-aot).
>   NU1202: Package System.Globalization.Extensions 4.3.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299) / win10-x86-aot. Package System.Globalization.Extensions 4.3.0 supports:
>     - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
>     - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
>     - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
>     - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
>     - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
>     - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)

Why? It worked without problems just a few days ago? Now it won't even install.

Comment: 16299 is .net standard 2.0 compatible. Wait for next version of AutoMapper which includes .net standard 2.0 support: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/2575

Comment: I tried lowering my target and minimum, but got the same errors.

Comment: Also, the same project with 16299 as the target and minimum project works just fine on another computer. I tried repairing VS2017 but the problem persists.

Comment: don't delete the answer. You can answer own questions.

Comment: Ah, ok, done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it's most likely not related to automapper, but NuGet was messed up for some reason. I simply cleared the nuget cache, and now it works as intended.